# Brute forcing domain accounts without hashes

Tags: passwords, penetration-test

Recently I noticed that on windows 7 domains it is possible to run cmd through .bat file command as a non admin user, therefore giving access to all domain admin user names. My question is how much danger the domain is in, if not all admin users have passwords over 6 characters long and whether it is possible for attacker to brute force those user names without having password hashes at all?

Answer (score 1):

The main thing is to have policy on all users to lock accounts after few failed logons. This way no account can be brute forced quickly. This should include local accounts as well.

Another thing is to have strong passwords so you can't guess them with little attempts. E.g. by trying only 2-3-4 times after each user logon.

If the accounts are not locked it's possible to use various protocols to brute force them, like SMB and sometimes LDAP.